How to get every INP? PerformanceObserver is not returning the low values
When we open dev tools on a performance tab, there is a super nice list of every interaction with the site, and the timing with it.

Unfortunately, it is impossible to get that kind of data from PerformanceObserver, since for 'events' its returning only bigger values, and it is doing so very sporadically.
Any ideas how to get such a nice list of interactions?

What does this have to do with the Linux [perf] command?  I'm most familiar with perf stat ./a.out and perf record / perf report; is this a different perf sub-command, or is this mis-tagged?

Removed the perf tag (which is for linux perf command despite it's generic sounding name) and added javascript tag instead.

That screen uses a performance observer code btw :-)
Make sure you pass a durationThreshold otherwise it uses the default of 104 milliseconds:
const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
  list.getEntries().forEach((entry) => {
    console.log(entry.duration, entry);
  });
});

// Register the observer for events
observer.observe({ type: "event", buffered: true, durationThreshold: 0 });

Note this still won't be every duration as the minimum durationThreshold is 16 milliseconds even if you specify less (like I have there).
For that reason we also observe the first-input entry in the above screen (which has no minimum but only fires for the first interaction).

Thank you Barry for the code snippet. One thing I am having troubles with that code is, its returning entries that happened without user interaction, when the page was still loading (when Angular was starting components).
Any idea how can I filter for "real" user interactions?

Curious. It shouldn't be able to do that. Only "trusted " events (i.e. user generated events) should be emitted by the Event Timing API. Can you open another question with a minimal test case and link from here?
